# Как сделать переключатель, который сначала скрывает значения в текстовых полях, а потом возвращает их? js

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть переключатель, который должен скрывать значения, набранные на счётах в полях по каждой спице и в верхнем поле, которое показывает общий результат.
Если переключатель включен, то все значения отображаются:
[image: Переключатель включен]

Если переключатель выключить, то все поля с результатами обнулятся и при дальнейшем набор не будут отображаться:

[image: переключатель выключен]

А если его заново включить, то все ранее набранные значения должны появиться обратно, но у меня этого не происходит пока я не нажму на какую-нибудь фишку. Не пониvаю что нужно добавить в код, чтобы набранные значения отобразились после включения переключателя.

```js
let rows = document.querySelector('.rows');

rows.onclick = e => {
  let tar = e.target;
//проверяем точно ли нажата фишка, а не что-то другое
  if (tar.classList.contains('fishka')) {

    let row = tar.closest('.row');
    let sep = row.querySelector('.separator');

    let taken = +row.dataset.taken;
    let index = +tar.dataset.idx;


  if (sep) sep.classList.remove('separator');
  let newIdx = index + (index >= taken);
  let newSep = row.querySelector(`.fishka[data-idx="${newIdx}"]`);
  if (newSep) newSep.classList.add('separator');
  row.dataset.taken = newIdx;

  calcRowSum(row);

  }
}

function calcRowSum(row) {
  var checkbox = document.getElementById('demo1');
  if (checkbox.checked == true){
    let output = row.previousElementSibling;
    output.value = row.dataset.taken * row.dataset.mult;
    calcTotal();
  }
  else{
    let output = row.previousElementSibling;
      output.value = 0;
    calcTotal();
  }
}

function calcTotal() {
  let rowSums = [...document.querySelectorAll('.row-sum')];
  total.value = rowSums.reduce((a, v) => +v.value + a, 0);
}


//переключатель, который скрывает значения
demo1.onclick = function(){
var checkBoxStatus = document.getElementById("demo1").checked;
if (checkBoxStatus == true) {
 

let rowSums = [...document.querySelectorAll('.row-sum')];
total.value = rowSums.reduce((a, v) => +v.value + a, 0);

} else if (checkBoxStatus == false){
   
     let rowSums = [...document.querySelectorAll('.row-sum')];
    total.value = rowSums.reduce((a, v) => +v.value * 0, 0);
    rowSums.forEach((item, i) => {
      item.value=0;
    });
 }}

//задание на набор числа
  function getRandomIntInclusive(param){
    if (param==null) {
      min = Math.ceil(1);
      max = Math.floor(1000);
    } else {
      min=Math.ceil(1);
        max = param;
    }
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; //Максимум и минимум включаются
}

const btn = document.getElementById('number');
const div = document.getElementById('exer');

btn.onclick = function() {
  div.innerHTML = getRandomIntInclusive();
}

//задание на сложение 2 чисел
const plus = document.getElementById('sum');
let a = 0;
let b = 0;
plus.addEventListener('click', () => {
        a = getRandomIntInclusive();

        b = getRandomIntInclusive();
document.getElementById("exer").innerHTML = a + " + " + b;
});


//задание на вычитание
const minus = document.getElementById('minus');
minus.addEventListener('click', () => {
      max = getRandomIntInclusive(null);
      min = getRandomIntInclusive(max);
document.getElementById("exer").innerHTML = max + " - " + min;
});
```

```css
html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0;
}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.5;
  background-color: #EEE9E1;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}

h2 {
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 58px;
}

h3 {
    font-size: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 28px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

section {
    padding-top: 113px;
}

p {
    margin: 0;
}

ul, li {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

 /*переключатель, скрывающий результат, поле вывода суммы и поле, отображающее задания*/
.menu{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
position: relative;
    max-width: 1920px;
    min-width: 360px;
    margin: 0 auto;
width: 1500px;
margin-top: -100px;
margin-bottom: 50px;
}

/*стили для переключателя, который скрывает результаты*/
label { margin: 2em;}
input { display: none;}
input+label,
input+label::before,
input+label::after {
    -webkit-transition: all .2s;
    transition: all .2s;
}
input+label { /*поле, по которому ездит переключатель*/
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 150px;
    height: 64px;
    cursor: pointer;

border: 3px solid #5A3108;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
border-radius: 30px;
}

input+label::before { /*текст*/
    display: block;
    content: attr(data-off-label);
    position: absolute;

    right: 10px;
    color: #fff;

    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 22px;
    line-height: 60px;

}

/*стиль кружочка слева*/
input+label::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
    left: 1px;

    width: 56px;
    height: 56px;
    background-color: #96683B;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

input:checked+label::before { /*стиль текста справа*/
    content: attr(data-on-label);
    left: 14px;
    right: auto;
    color: #fff;
}

/*стиль кружочка справа*/
input:checked+label::after {
    left: 87px;
    width: 56px;
height: 56px;
background: #E2C898;
}

#demo1+label {  background-color: #E2C898; } /*цвет на выкл*/
#demo1+label::before {  color: #96683B; } /*цвет текста на выкл*/
#demo1:checked+label {  background-color: #96683B;} /*цвет на вкл*/
#demo1:checked+label::before { color: #E2C898; } /*цвет текста на вкл*/

 /*поле вывода суммы*/
.total {
box-sizing: border-box;
width: 511px;
height: 64px;
background: #96683B;
border: 3px solid #5A3108;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px #96683B;
border-radius: 20px;
text-align: center;
font-family: 'Roboto';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 48px;
line-height: 56px;
color: #F9F9F9;
text-align: center;
margin: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
justify-content: center;
overflow: auto;
}

/*поле, которое отображает задания*/
.exer {
box-sizing: border-box;
text-align: center;
margin-left: -150px;
top: 50px;
background: #96683B;
border: 3px solid #5A3108;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
border-radius: 20px;
font-family: 'Roboto';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 38px;
line-height: 56px;
width: 339px;
height: 64px;
color: #F9F9F9;
}

/*Рамка со спицами (подложка)-игровое поле*/
.pole{
background: url('../img/1.svg') no-repeat center top / cover;
width: 700px;
height: 818.87px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
margin-top: -50px;
}

/*Класс, в котором заключены все ряды и поля для вывода значений, набранных на каждом ряду*/
.rows {
    max-width: 1920px;
    min-width: 360px;
}


/*Поля для вывода значений, набранных на каждом ряду*/
.row-sum {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;

width: 250px;
height: 50px;
background: #DAB26A;
border: 3px solid #96683B;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
border-radius: 20px;

font-family: 'Roboto';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 38px;
line-height: 56px;
text-align: center;

color: #F9F9F9;
margin-left: -370px;
}


#result1{
margin-top: -30px;
}

/*Класс, в котором лежат все фишки-ряды*/
.row {
display: flex;
margin-top: -55px;
margin-bottom: 14px;
margin-right: 80px;
margin-left: 60px;
gap: 2px;
}

/*Стили для фишек*/
.fishka{
 cursor: pointer;
}


/*Разделение фишек*/
.separator {
  margin-left: auto;
}

/*Задания*/
.task{
margin-left: 760px;
margin-top:  -740px;
}

.number, .sum, .minus{
    box-sizing: border-box;
cursor: pointer;
width: 253px;
height: 54px;

position: absolute;
margin-top: -225px;
margin-left: 45px;
background: #DAB26A;
border: 3px solid #96683B;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
border-radius: 20px;

font-family: 'Roboto';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 28px;
line-height: 56px;
text-align: center;
color: #F9F9F9;
}

#sum{
margin-top:-160px;
}

#minus{
margin-top:-95px;
}

#number:focus{
    background-color: #A07141;
}

#sum:focus{
    background-color: #A07141;
}

#minus:focus{
    background-color: #A07141;
}

.control{
    margin-left: 760px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

/*кнопка для обнуления*/
.reset{
box-sizing: border-box;
cursor: pointer;
width: 339px;
height: 64px;

background: #96683B;
border: 3px solid #5A3108;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
border-radius: 20px;

font-family: 'Roboto';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 28px;
line-height: 56px;
text-align: center;
color: #F9F9F9;
}

/*кнопка для смены уровня*/
.level{
    box-sizing: border-box;
cursor: pointer;
width: 339px;
height: 64px;

margin-top: 15px;
background: #96683B;
border: 3px solid #5A3108;
box-shadow: 0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
border-radius: 20px;
font-family: 'Roboto';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 28px;
line-height: 56px;
text-align: center;
color: #F9F9F9;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>
<body>

<!-- Кнопка для скрывания результатов, Результат вычислений и поле для вывода заданий" -->
<section id="menu">
<div class="menu">

  <div class="check">
    <input type="checkbox" id="demo1" onclick="" checked>
  <label for="demo1" data-on-label="Вкл." data-off-label="Выкл."></label>
  </div>

    <output name="total" id="total" class="total">0</output>
    <output name="exer" id="exer" class="exer">Выбери задание</output>

</div>
</section>

<!-- Игровое поле, которое состоит из рамки, спиц и фишек -->
<section id="pole" class="pole">
<div class="rows">

<output id="result1" class="row-sum">0</output>
<div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="1000000000">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka separator" data-idx="0">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="1">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="2">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="3">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="4">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="5">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="6">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="7">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="8">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="9">
</div>

<output id="result" class="row-sum">0</output>
  <div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="100000000">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka separator" data-idx="0">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="1">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="2">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="3">
      <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="4">
      <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="5">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="6">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="7">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="8">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="9">
  </div>

 <output id="result" class="row-sum">0</output>
    <div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="10000000">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka separator" data-idx="0">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="1">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="2">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="3">
      <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="4">
      <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="5">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="6">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="7">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="8">
      <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="9">
    </div>

    <output id="result" class="row-sum">0</output>
      <div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="1000000">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka separator" data-idx="0">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="1">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="2">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="3">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="4">
        <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="5">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="6">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="7">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="8">
        <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="9">
      </div>

<output id="result" class="row-sum">0</output>
<div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="100000">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka separator" data-idx="0">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="1">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="2">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="3">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="4">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="5">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="6">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="7">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="8">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="9">
</div>

<output id="result" class="row-sum">0</output>
<div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="10000">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka separator" data-idx="0">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="1">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="2">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="3">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="4">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="5">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="6">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="7">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="8">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="9">
</div>

<output id="result" class="row-sum">0</output>
<div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="1000">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka separator" data-idx="0">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="1">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="2">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="3">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="4">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="5">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="6">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="7">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="8">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="9">
</div>

<output id="result" class="row-sum">0</output>
<div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="100">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka separator" data-idx="0">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="1">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="2">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="3">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="4">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="5">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="6">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="7">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="8">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="9">
</div>

<output id="result" class="row-sum">0</output>

<div class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="10">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka separator" data-idx="0">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="1">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="2">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="3">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="4">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="5">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="6">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="7">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="8">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="9">
</div>

<output id="result" class="row-sum">0</output>

<div id="row" class="row" data-taken="0" data-mult="1" transform="0px">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka separator" data-idx="0">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="1">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="2">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="3">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="4">
  <img src="img/тёмная.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="5">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="6">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="7">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="8">
  <img src="img/светлая.svg" class="fishka" data-idx="9">
</div>
</div>


<div class="task" id="task">
<img src="img/задание.svg" width="339" height="297" alt="">
  <button type="button" name="number" id="number" value="number" class="number">
  ЧИСЛО
  </button>
  <button type="button" name="sum" id="sum" value="sum" class="sum">
СЛОЖЕНИЕ
  </button>
  <button type="button" name="minus" id="minus" value="minus" class="minus">
ВЫЧИТАНИЕ
  </button>
</div>

<div class="control">
  <button type="button" name="reset" id="reset" value="reset" class="reset" onClick="window.location.reload();">
  ОБНУЛИТЬ
  </button>

  <button name="level" value="level" class="level" onClick= window.location.href='abacus_level_2.html'>
  УРОВЕНЬ 2
  </button>
</div>

</section>

<script src="js/test.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы забыли возвращать элементам total и каждому row их значение после повторного нажатия на переключатель.
Исправный код:

```js
        let rows = document.querySelector('.rows');

        rows.onclick = e => {
            let tar = e.target;
            //проверяем точно ли нажата фишка, а не что-то другое
            if (tar.classList.contains('fishka')) {

                let row = tar.closest('.row');
                let sep = row.querySelector('.separator');

                let taken = +row.dataset.taken;
                let index = +tar.dataset.idx;


                if (sep) sep.classList.remove('separator');
                let newIdx = index + (index >= taken);
                let newSep = row.querySelector(`.fishka[data-idx="${newIdx}"]`);
                if (newSep) newSep.classList.add('separator');
                row.dataset.taken = newIdx;

                calcRowSum(row);

            }
        }

        function calcRowSum(row) {
            var checkbox = document.getElementById('demo1');
            if (checkbox.checked == true) {
                let output = row.previousElementSibling;
                output.value = row.dataset.taken * row.dataset.mult;
                calcTotal();
            }
            else {
                let output = row.previousElementSibling;
                output.value = 0;
                calcTotal();
            }
        }

        function calcTotal() {
            let rowSums = [...document.querySelectorAll('.row-sum')];
            total.value = rowSums.reduce((a, v) => +v.value + a, 0);
        }


        //переключатель, который скрывает значения
        demo1.onclick = function () {
            var checkBoxStatus = document.getElementById("demo1").checked;
            if (checkBoxStatus) {


                let rowSums = [...document.querySelectorAll('.row-sum')];
                rowSums.forEach((item, i) => {
                    const data = item.nextElementSibling
                    item.value = Number(data.dataset.taken) * Number(data.dataset.mult)
                });
                calcTotal()
            } else {

                let rowSums = [...document.querySelectorAll('.row-sum')];
                total.value = rowSums.reduce((a, v) => +v.value * 0, 0);
                rowSums.forEach((item, i) => {
                    item.value = 0;
                });
            }
        }

        //задание на набор числа
        function getRandomIntInclusive(param) {
            if (!param) {
                min = Math.ceil(1);
                max = Math.floor(1000);
            } else {
                min = Math.ceil(1);
                max = param;
            }
            return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; //Максимум и минимум включаются
        }

        const btn = document.getElementById('number');
        const div = document.getElementById('exer');

        btn.onclick = function () {
            div.innerHTML = getRandomIntInclusive();
        }

        //задание на сложение 2 чисел
        const plus = document.getElementById('sum');
        let a = 0;
        let b = 0;
        plus.addEventListener('click', () => {
            a = getRandomIntInclusive();
            b = getRandomIntInclusive();
            document.getElementById("exer").innerHTML = a + " + " + b;
        });


        //задание на вычитание
        const minus = document.getElementById('minus');
        minus.addEventListener('click', () => {
            max = getRandomIntInclusive(null);
            min = getRandomIntInclusive(max);
            document.getElementById("exer").innerHTML = max + " - " + min;
        });
```

Comment: Да! Спасибо за помощь!!!